# How to get included XML binding in DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a DataBinding class `ActivityMainBinding` where the XMl looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>
```

And the content_main.xml is another binding

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

Now, in my activity I set the content view like this.

```
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now I can access all XML elemets using this binding. like

```
        Toolbar toolbar = activityMainBinding.toolbar;
```

but some of my widgets are in the included layout which is `ContentMainBinding`

Now, how can I create a `ContentMainBinding` instance from `ActivityMainBinding` ?

I tried

```
        contentMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(activityMainBinding.container);
```

But, its crashing with error

```
         ActivityMainBindingImpl cannot be cast to ContentMainBinding
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to add `<layout>----</layout>` tag in your content_main.xml file. You need to set id of included layout like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layoutcontent_main" android:id="@+id/contentMain" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>
```

Then you can directly access included layout view using

```
ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
activityMainBinding.contentMain.recyclerView.setAdapter();
```

Answer (score 3):

Add id to include tag

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/included"
    layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

And in code use

```
activityMainBinding.included.recyclerView
```

Check that [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-that-include-thing-1c8791dd6038)